# Exclude field from a document based on another field value mongodb mongoose

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a `users` schema in which there is a `companies` field which I only want to select if `role` field value is **admin** else it should not be returned in find query.

`user` Schema:

```
const userInfoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ...,
  companies: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'companyinfos',
    },
  ],
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['user', 'admin', 'employee'],
    default: 'user',
  },
});
```

I have tried to solve this by using pre find hook but was unable to exclude the companies field.

```
userInfoSchema.post(/^find/, function (doc, next) {
  if (doc.role !== 'admin') {
    this.find({}).select('-companies');
  }

  next();
});
```

Or is there any way to conditionally set `select` in the `companies` field in the userInfoSchema based on the `role` value?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

use aggregate

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      companies: {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $eq: [
              "$role",
              "admin"
            ]
          },
          "then": "$companies",
          "else": 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      companies: {
        $ne: 0
      }
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/I8HGvz6h7MP